# How Long is the iPad Roation Duration?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, rotation, duration

Pretty simple question but I can't seem to find an answer. Does anyone know the length in seconds the duration of the iPad Roation animation? I can guess that it's something short like 0.5 or 1 second long but if anyone knows an exact number it would be handy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

If you are trying to do something in sync use the above method and grab the duration. And ideally also initiate the animation you wish to perform there as well.

Also I believe its 0.4, most standard animations are 0.3 or 0.4s. IIRC